# Transforming with Quaternions (Set a Parent->Child hierarchy to a goal orientation described from the child's POV.)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, vectormath

Here is the closest thing I can come up with but the position is not correct....
The parent's goal position is what I am trying to determine. Any help is appreciated!

```
Quaternion rotation = goal.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(child.rotation) * parent.rotation;
parent.MoveRotation(rotation);
Vector3 position = goal.position + (Quaternion.Inverse(parent.rotation) * child.rotation) * (parent.position - child.position);
parent.MovePosition(position);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your graphic correctly what you have is

- a parent object
- a child object which is arbitrary positioned and rotated relative to the parent

and what you are trying to achieve is

- set the rotation and position of the parent in a way so that the child matches a certain given rotation and position

You are somewhat pretty close.

**Ignoring the scale** (assuming there is no scaling involved in the entire hierarchy until the parent object) basically you can simplified say

```
finalChildRotation = targetParentRotation * localDeltaRotation;
finalChildPosition = targetParentPosition + parentRotation * localDeltaPosition;
```

We already know

```
var finalChildRotation = goal.rotation;
var finalChildPosition = goal.position;

var localDeltaRotation = child.localRotation;
var localDeltaPosition = child.localPosition;
```

so you can resolve the rest in the order

```
// orientation as only one unknown -> basically simply rotate back the delta from the given goal rotation
var targetParentRotation =  finalChildRotation * Quaternion.Inverse(localDeltaRotation);
// Now that we have our final rotation you can easily calculate the position
var targetParentPosition = finalChildPosition - targetParentRotation * localDeltaPosition;
```

---

Little demo

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform goal;
    public Transform parent;
    public Transform child;

    [ContextMenu("Place")]
    public void Place()
    {
        var finalChildRotation = goal.rotation;
        var finalChildPosition = goal.position;

        var localDeltaRotation = child.localRotation;
        var localDeltaPosition = child.localPosition;

        var targetParentRotation = finalChildRotation * Quaternion.Inverse(localDeltaRotation);
        var targetParentPosition = finalChildPosition - targetParentRotation * localDeltaPosition;

        parent.rotation = targetParentRotation;
        parent.position = targetParentPosition;
    }
}
```

[image]

---

However, if there is also scaling in play this will probably get more complex!

Comment: Thank you for the exceptionally clear answer to this question. I am grateful.